# Need a command or program to download all images

Tags: download, command, wget

I need software or command to download all images from a website that use below formul :

```
website/images/imgs/folder1/folder2/imageName.png

folder1 = This folder start from 0 and continues to infinity.
folder2 = This folder start from 0 and continues to infinity.
imageName = Image name start from 0.png and continues to infinity.
```

If there is the folder server show 403 Forbidden and if folder not found server response 404 Not Found
And for image if there is image server show image and if image not exist server response 404 Not Found
I need software or command to download with this formul

Some example of images :

```
website/images/imgs/0/0/0.png
website/images/imgs/0/25/36.png
website/images/imgs/10/0/158.png
website/images/imgs/5/5/5.png
website/images/imgs/11/285/350.png
website/images/imgs/8/12/45.png
website/images/imgs/9/200/350.png
```

And I need to save them like below :

```
/home/me/downloads/images/imgs/0/0/0.png
/home/me/downloads/images/imgs/0/25/36.png
/home/me/downloads/images/imgs/10/0/158.png
/home/me/downloads/images/imgs/5/5/5.png
/home/me/downloads/images/imgs/11/285/350.png
/home/me/downloads/images/imgs/8/12/45.png
/home/me/downloads/images/imgs/9/200/350.png
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for numbered files is **{startnumber..lastnumber}**, so in the below case 0 is starting and 99999 last(you can change as per your requirement)

You can use the below command to download all images from /0/0/ folder. But you need to change the foldername  with next foldername manually to download next folder's images.

```
wget http://example.com/images/imgs/0/0/{0..99999}.png
```

Or try below command :)

```
wget http://example.com/images/imgs/{0..999}/{0..999}/{0..99999}.png
```